# What the difference between 'it exists' and 'it does exist'?

Tags: grammar

What the difference between 'it exists' and 'it does exist'? I want to know.

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times. See   https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301381/difference-between-he-does-work-and-he-works

Comment: absolutely not.